# Accord du participe passé en conjonction avec un participe présent

Tags: grammaire, accord, participe-passé, participe-présent

Dans sa lettre de motivation, ma sœur voudrait écrire qu'elle a toujours été intéressée par les soins de santé. Quelle orthographe devrais-je lui conseiller ?

> 1. Les soins de santé m'ayant toujours *intéressé*, je...
> 2. Les soins de santé m'ayant toujours *intéressée*, je...
> 3. Les soins de santé m'ayant toujours *intéressés*, je...

Nous avons trouvé une alternative sous la forme suivante :

> Ayant toujours été intéressée par les soins de santé, je...

Mais la question reste : que faudrait-il idéalement écrire si l'on s'en tenait à la formulation initiale ?

Je privilégierais la deuxième possibilité car peu importe le temps, le complément d'objet direct, « m' », précède le verbe et correspond à ma sœur. Elle préfère la troisième option sans pour autant pouvoir l'expliquer, mais met en cause le participe présent. Nous sommes d'accord sur l'éviction de la première possibilité.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Même accord que dans :

> Les soins de santé m'ayant toujours surprise, je…

L'auxiliaire *avoir* demande l'accord du participe passé avec le COD *me*, lorsqu'il est placé avant.

*Me* pouvant être COD ou COI, selon les cas, il est facile de se tromper lorsque la prononciation n'aide pas.

L'existence de la forme pronominale « s'intéresser à », comme dans « M'étant intéressée aux soins de santé » ne fait que compliquer les choses, mais on remarquera que l'accord se fait avec la même entité, qui n'est plus véritablement objet direct, mais essentiellement sujet dans cette proposition.